# Preserve a HTTPEntity without consuming the stream

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, httpentity

I'm using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient and I'm trying to access the payload of the request HTTPEntity without consuming the underlying stream.
I tried using

```
EntityUtils.toString(someEntity);
```

but this consumes the stream.
I just want to preserve the payload which was sent in a HTTP request to a String object for e.g.

Sample Code:

```
String uri = "someURI";
HttpPut updateRequest = new HttpPut(uri);         
updateRequest.setEntity(myHttpEntity);
```

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HttpEntity must be `repeatable` for it to be repeatedly consumable. The method `isRepeatable()` shows whether or not this is the case.

Two entities are repeatable:

- StringEntity
- ByteArrayEntity

This means you have to add one of these to the original request so you can keep using using its content.

```
public void doExample() {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("some_url");
    httpPut.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    StringEntity jsonEntityOrso = new StringEntity("{ \"hello\": \"some message\" }");
    httpPut.setEntity(jsonEntityOrso);
    StringEntity reusableEntity = (StringEntity) httpPut.getEntity();
    String hello = readInputStream(reusableEntity.getContent());
    String hello2 = readInputStream(reusableEntity.getContent());
    boolean verify = hello.equals(hello2); // returns true
}

private String readInputStream(InputStream stream) {
    return new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Comment: I will check that. I'm using StringEntity already but, when I try to use EntityUtils.toString twice. I get IOException: "Stream is closed ..." . But I will verify if I'm using everywhere String Entities. Merry Christma by the way.

Comment: Merry Christmas. You're right by the way. It seems the EntityUtils poses a problem by closing the stream after getting the content. I've changed my answer to read the String directly from the Entity instead.

Comment: Worked for me. Just had to change from StringEntity to HTTPEntity, because of class cast exception.